# ¿ Xcode como cambiar el nombre del proyecto o crear un esqueleto del proyecto?

Tags: ios, xcode

Tengo creado un esqueleto de inicio de un proyecto con un nombre concreto y unas librerías. Este esqueleto de proyecto lo quiero aprovechar para construir en un futuro otros proyectos. 
¿ Como debo trabajar para reutilizarlo ? 
Ahora mismo necesito cambiar el nombre del proyecto por el nuevo en todas las referencias que tenga en el árbol que se creado del proyecto. También tendría que cambiar el 'Bundle identifier' y no se si me dejo alguna cosa mas.

Comment: Para hacer eso puedes configurarte templates. Mira esto http://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-create-custom-project-templates-in-xcode-7

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda